# XAML, WPF "Not enough storage is available to process this command"

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, exception, devexpress

This is an interesting one. I randomly see this error in one my apps. It doesn't specify whether it's memory storage of file storage.
File system:  I check the local C drive, and it has more than enough. 
Memory: Plenty left on a 32G RAM

Posted it to see if anyone else came across something similar.

[image]

Comment: If possible, could you post that error message as text instead of an image? Ctrl+C on the dialog *should* copy it to the clipboard for you.

Comment: Do you run that application as 32-bit or 64-bit process?

Comment: Most instances I can find of this error seem to be due to unmanaged resource handle depletion, usually GDI resources.  Are doing any image manipulation in your application?

Comment: @Evk It's a 32 Bit app due to some native dependencies

Comment: @BradleyUffner Interesting idea, we do have Wpf controls inside of Winform containers.

Comment: Are you starting multiple threads in which you use dependency objects?